# JSON Parsing Swift using JSONPlaceholder

Tags: ios, json, swift, json-serialization

I'm playing with Swift and JSONPlaceholder. I want to retrieve all the data contained in: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos

I created a function that is acceding to the url, downloading the JSON but then I don't know how can I obtain the title and the thumbnailUrl to pass then for populate the tableView. In the past I used this code but now it's not working because on the JSONPlaceholder there are no array.

Any help for re-arrange the code for read and obtain the jsonplaceholder elements?

```
func loadList(){

    let url = URL(string: urlReceived)

    var myNews = NewInfo()

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print("ERROR")
        }
        else{
            do {
                if let content = data{
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: .mutableContainers)

                    //print(myJson)
                    if let jsonData = myJson as? [String : Any] {

                        if let myResults = jsonData["list"] as? [[String : Any]]{
                            //dump(myResults)

                            for value in myResults{
                                //Read time string from root
                                if let time = value ["dt_txt"] as? String{

                                    myNews.time = time
                                }
                                //Read main container
                                if let main = value["main"]
                                    as? [String : Any]{
                                    if let temperature = main["temp"] as? Double {
                                        myNews.temperature = String(temperature)
                                    }
                                }
                                //Read from weather container
                                if let weather = value["weather"] as? [[String: Any]]{
                                    for value in weather{
                                        if let weatherContent = value["description"] as? String{
                                            myNews.weatherDescription = weatherContent
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                                self.myTableViewDataSource.append(myNews)

                            }
                            dump(self.myTableViewDataSource)

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch{

            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}//End func
```

Comment: I know, this is not answer for you question, but did you try to use swiftyJSON library? It's easy to use, and easy to understand.

Comment: Actually no  You think it can solve my problem?

Comment: With Alamofire and SwiftyJSON libraries, you can write a very clean and readable code, something like this: https://imgur.com/a/xvzqoO6. If you print(json), you can see the structure and you can use .arrayValue or .dictionaryValue.

Comment: I have Alamofire imported... I need to try with SwiftyJSON

Comment: I think it will help you :) Just let me know :)

Comment: I really hope so! I need to achieve one task and I'm really in trouble... Thank you anyway :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, so with Alamofire + SwiftyJSON, you can do this:

```
func loadList(){

    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"
    AF.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            print(json)

            for value in json.arrayValue {
                let url = value.dictionaryValue["url"]!.stringValue
                let albumId = value.dictionaryValue["albumId"]!.stringValue
                let thumbnailUrl = value.dictionaryValue["thumbnailUrl"]!.stringValue
                let id = value.dictionaryValue["id"]!.stringValue
                let title = value.dictionaryValue["title"]!.stringValue

                // Add this album to array.
                let album = AlbumModel(id: id, albumId: albumId, title: title, thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl)
                albums.append(album)

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I made model for values

```
class AlbumModel {

var id: String?
var albumId: String?
var title: String?
var thumbnailUrl: String?

init(id: String?, albumId: String?, title: String?, thumbnailUrl: String?){

    self.id = id
    self.albumId = albumId
    self.title = title
    self.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl

   }
}
```

After that, just create an array like `var albums = [AlbumModel]()` and you can append all the albums to this. Easy to use after in tableViewcell (example: `albums[indexPath.row].id`)

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply! But what is AlbumMode?

Comment: That's really great! Thank you so much!!